# Port-forwarding for port 80 doesn't work for requests from inside the LAN (works for WAN)

Tags: networking, router, portforwarding

### In Short

- When I'm typing in the browser *mydom.com* :

  - from WAN, I get the page from my HTTP-server (from 192.168.14.65:80).
  - from LAN I get my routers config page (from 192.168.14.1:80). (I want it to forward the request to my server, like it's doing for WAN)
- When I'm typing in the browser *mydom.com:2134*

  - I get, both from LAN and WAN, the server's page (from 192.168.14.65:80).

#### Longer

- I have a router, there i configured the port forwarding 80 to 192.168.14.65:80.
- I have a computer inside a LAN with HTTP server on it. inner address: 192.168.14.65
- I have a domain that points to my IP,lets say- mydom.com.
- When I'm typing in the browser *mydom.com* from outside my LAN, I get the page from my server (from 192.168.14.65:80)
- when I type *mydom.com* in a browser from a computer that is inside my LAN I get the configuration page of my router (from 192.168.14.1:80)
- Moreover, if I configure to forward any port other then 80 (lets say port 2134) to my server's 80 port (so - port 2134 to 192.168.14.65:80) it works, meaning when I'm *mydom.com:2134* it works in LAN and WAN.

#### Hardware/Software Specs

- The name I have on my router: NB403 - VDSL2 GATEWAY Vtech
- The server (192.168.14.65) is Ubuntu-server 18.04 with nginx/1.14.0

Answer (score 1):

This is not a question but rather a bug report to your routers vendor.

The tricky part is actually IPv4 or the PAT/NAT reflection part of it.
Your DNS name points to the official IPv4 of your router.
So, when your "outside" your router only does port forwarding.
But when you're "inside" your router needs to do two types of PAT/NAT for the same connection.:

1. hide your private IP for access to a public IP (needed to access anything in public IP space/ internet) (source NAT)
2. forward your request to the internal servers IP (destination NAT)

This confuses a lot of consumer NAT devices.

There are three solutions.

1. Use IPv6. With IPv6 there' no NAT/PAT needed and it works without issues.
2. Use a router that can to NAT reflection.
3. use "split DNS". That means your internal DNS server answers with your internal servers IP when asked for mydom.com. This way the connection is directly to the servers private IP when internal. No NAT involved.

Regards,
Michael